# The speed of sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I'm using a sqlite3 in IOS Development.
I found a strange problem.
My database is 1.1MB and it has about 20000 records.
When I use sqlite3_open to open the database, I find it takes almost 2 seconds in IPHONE4 and just 0.03 seconds in IPAD2.
Am I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the different between A4 CPU & A5 CPU.
I use a Loading Page to deal with this problem.